# UWP Release Compile with Error

Tags: xaml, compiler-errors, uwp, uwp-xaml

When i Compile my UWP App in Debug mode all work good.

When i Compile in Release version i received an error

'File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value'

**in x86**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: JSI_W10, Configuration: Release x86 ------
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x86\Release\Login_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x86\Release\Maschera_Test.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x86\Release\Registration_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x86\Release\ResetForgot_Password.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x86\Release\Send_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x86\Release\The_Brochure_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x86\Release\The_Home_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x86\Release\The_Image_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x86\Release\The_Video_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x86\Release\The_Home_Page.g.vb(44,21): error BC30456: 'Lbl_Search' is not a member of 'The_Home_Page'.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
========== App Bundle: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
```

**in x64**

```
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\Login_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\Maschera_Test.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\Registration_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\ResetForgot_Password.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\Send_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Brochure_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Global_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Home_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Image_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Video_Page.g.vb(1,1): warning BC42034: File name already declared with a different GUID and checksum value.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Home_Page.g.vb(44,21): error BC30456: 'Lbl_Search' is not a member of 'The_Home_Page'.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\The_Global_Page.xaml(201,107): error BC30456: 'Image_Tapped' is not a member of 'The_Global_Page'.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\The_Global_Page.xaml(202,111): error BC30456: 'TextBlock_Tapped' is not a member of 'The_Global_Page'.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Global_Page.g.vb(777,21): error BC30456: 'Lbl_Search' is not a member of 'The_Global_Page'.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Global_Page.g.vb(783,38): error BC30311: Value of type 'ToggleButton' cannot be converted to 'Button'.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Global_Page.g.vb(786,35): error BC30311: Value of type 'ToggleButton' cannot be converted to 'Button'.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Global_Page.g.vb(789,38): error BC30311: Value of type 'ToggleButton' cannot be converted to 'Button'.
1>C:\Sorgenti\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\JSI_W10\obj\x64\Release\The_Global_Page.g.vb(792,33): error BC30311: Value of type 'ToggleButton' cannot be converted to 'Button'.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
```

**Pay Attenction** the  TOGGLE Button was in an OLD release... now i haven't like  Image_tapped and TextBlock_tapped event....

I can remove them beacause i can't SEE Them !!!!!

Anyone have an idea ??
Thanks

Comment: remove /bin and /obj directories from your projects

Comment: I have solved. I have deleted a BIN directory. Now all works good

Answer (score 3):

Try below steps.

1. Clean the solution.
2. In your source folder, you will have `bin` and `obj` directories. Delete them completely.
3. Now try to build the solution and see if it works.